# How to find an orthogonal complement for P3 given following condition?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the inner product of the vector space of polynomial functions of degree 3 to be:

$$ \langle p,q\rangle = \int_0^1 p(x)q(x) dx $$

let S be a subspace of $P_3(\mathbb R)$, such as

$$ S = \{ p ∈ P_3(\mathbb R) : p(1) = 0 \} $$

I need to find the orthogonal complement of S.

I know I have to first find a basis for S. Which would be:

$$ S = [x-1, x^2-1, x^3-1]$$

But I got stuck here. How do I find the base for the orthogonal complement of S (there is $S^\perp$)?

This is my main difficulty, but there is also a second part to this problem.

Given $p ∈ P_3(\mathbb R)$ find the vector $p_1 ∈ S$ and $p_2 ∈ S^\perp$ such that $p = p_1 + p_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $S$ is three dimensional, $S^\perp $ is one dimensional, so all you have to do is to find $q(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d \in  S^\perp $.

You need to have  $$\int _0^1 (x-1)q(x)dx=0 $$ and $$\int _0^1 (x^2-1)q(x)dx=0 $$ and $$\int _0^1 (x^3-1)q(x)dx=0 $$ I found integration by parts very useful here.

You can solve these equations and find the coeffcients of $q(x)$

The  second part follows easily.

Answer (score 0):

My Recommendation would be to first find a basis for $S$, extend this to a basis for $P_3$, and then using the Gram-Schmidt algorithm you can orthogonalize the total basis.  Notice that while $\{x-1, x^2 - 1, x^3-1\}$ is a basis for $S$, you can extend this to a basis for $P_3$ by simply including the constant function $1$:

$$
P_3 \;\; =\;\; \text{Span}\left \{1, x-1, x^2-1, x^3 - 1 \right \}.
$$

Perform Gram-Schmidt on these vectors starting with your basis for $S$ and then finish the algorithm with $p(x) = 1$ at the end.